# Groovy files throwing ClassNotFoundException in Java Spring Boot application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy, eclipse-plugin

I have updated my STS to v4 few days ago,since then I unable to run my application which has groovy files.

I have installed Groovy Development plugin and tried to build the project using the maven command "**clean install**".

Maven build has been successfully executed, but when I started my project it throws that the Groovy class has not found exception.

I tried cleaning the project many times, but getting the same ClassNotFoundException for the Groovy classes.

My STS v4 installation details:

[image]

Java Build path details:
[image]

Error Details, while I am running the project:

[image]

That parser class is the groovy class which throws ClassNotFoundException.
Moreover, I the project explorer some strange icon is shown next to those kind of groovy files.

[image]

I am also attaching the maven build details, 
[image]

[image]

these build information shows that those groovy files are compiled successfully, but still it throws ClassNotFoundException while starting the application.

NOTE: I gave **clean - build**, "**clean compile**" and updated maven project more than 15 times. Yet no luck.

Please help me in reSolving this issue SO!

Comment: Post text, not images, and specify what class exactly isn't being found.

Comment: Sorry for that, PimuXmlResponseParser(which is a Groovy class) is the class which throws ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!

Compiler mismatch is the culprit here.